# Unable to resolve dependency Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and it worked..
you just need to reset dependencies in app.gradle file like old one as

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

to this...

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```